# How to replace an empty output from dplyr::filter()

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tibble

I have a dataset `dt` with a column named `x` which contains numerics and unexpected values. My goal is to retrieve a value from a lookup table based on the value of `x` without cleaning `x` (because there are unexpected values), by using the `dplyr::filter()` function. If the condition statements is not found in the lookup table, the `dplyr::filter()` return an empty tibble and I want to replace this output by the value of `0.0` as an array.

Here is an example of my code:

```
dt <- tibble(x = c(0, -1, 0.5))
lookup_table <- tibble(
         lower_bound = c(0, 0.2, 0.5),
         upper_bound = c(0.2, 0.5, 1000000),
         output = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
        )
y <- lookup_table %>% filter(lower_bound <= dt$x, upper_bound > dt$x) %>% select(output) %>% pull() %>% if_else(length() != 0, lookup_table %>% filter(lower_bound <= dt$x, upper_bound > dt$x) %>% select(output) %>% pull(), 0.0)
y
>>> [1]  0.1 0.0 0.3 # Expected output
```

Thanks you,

John

EDIT: Please notice that `dt` and the lookup table have not necessarily the same number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. We can combine the `findInterval` and `gsub` R functions together with `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


dt <- tibble(x = c(0, -1, 0.5))
lookup_table <- tibble(
         lower_bound = c(0, 0.2, 0.5),
         upper_bound = c(0.2, 0.5, 1000000),
         output = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
        )
y <- arrange(lookup_table, lower_bound)[as.numeric( dt$x %>% findInterval(lookup_table %>% arrange(lower_bound) %>% select( lower_bound ) %>% pull() ) %>% gsub(pattern=0, replacement=NA)), 'output'] %>% pull() %>% replace_na(0)
y
>>> [1]  0.1 0.0 0.3 # Actual output
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit easier to pull `x` into the tibble and then create a new column with the output you need using `if_else`.

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- tibble(x = c(0, -1, 0.5))
lookup_table <- tibble(
         lower_bound = c(0, 0.2, 0.5),
         upper_bound = c(0.2, 0.5, 1000000),
         output = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
        )
# Create column with output  
lookup_table <- lookup_table %>% 
  bind_cols(dt) %>% 
  mutate(y = if_else(lower_bound <= x & upper_bound > x, output, 0))

lookup_table %>% pull(y)
# [1] 0.1 0.0 0.3
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, Dt is not necessarily the same length as lookup_table. Your solution won't work all the time!

Comment: If `dt` and `lookup_table` table have different lengths I think you would need a common identifier across both - otherwise there would be no way to tell which element of `dt` relates to which interval in `lookup_table`. If there was a vector or column to link the two then you could merge and follow the same process.